# How to set a timer using jQuery to sent HTTP post data of HTML form

Tags: jquery, timer, http-post, form-submit

I have an HTML form that I need to post to the server with HTTP POST and input data.

Specifically, I need to send only the parameter values of all the checkboxes that are checked in the form.

I need to do it if the user doesn't do it himself in 10 minutes.

I am not sure the best way to achieve this but for now I am trying to use jQuery do that but sadly I don't know anything about JavaScipt or jQuery so I am trying to learn it but failing to achieve something as simple as that.

I need to the run the following after 10 minutes since the page on which the form is loads.

```
    $("document").ready(function() {            
        var checkedInputElements = $(":input[value=true]");
        var paramNames = [];
        jQuery.each(checkedInputElements, function() {
            var paramName = $(this).attr("name");
            paramNames.push(paramName);
        });
        $("form").submit(function() {
            jQuery.post({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "http://localhost:8080/wickedlynotsmart/auto-submit-form",
              data: paramNames
          });
          return true;
        });
    });
```

I am not sure if the code above is correct or not. I am still working on it.
Could someone suggest me a guide which I could use to write a timer so that this code runs after the 10 minutes are over since the page loads?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jspf" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>wikedlynotsmart.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css" />" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shThemeDefault.css" />" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shCore.js" />"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushJava.js" />"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         SyntaxHighlighter.all()
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        //auto-submit-form javascipt code
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" />
    <div id="thing">
        <form id="form" action="<c:url value="/wikedlynotsmart/auto-submit-form" />" method="post">             
            <ol>
                <c:forEach items="${things}" var="thing">
                    <li>${thing.something}</li>
                    <c:forEach items="${matters}" var="matter">
                        <table>         
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid${thing.id}-mid${matter.id}" value="true"/></td>
                                <td>${matter.somematter}</td>
                            </tr>       
                        </table>                    
                    </c:forEach><br></br>
                </c:forEach>        
            </ol>   
            <input type="submit" value="submit the thing" class="button"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jsp" />    
</body>
</html>
```

This is the page I am working on and trying to get things work for me.

Comment: FYI; "To achieve the best performance when using :input to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":input")." http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks Stefan, but the thing is I don't even know much about CSS selectors. `$(form input[value="true"])` is all I could come up apart from `$(":input[value=true]");` :(

Comment: What type of elements are you trying to select? The `value="true"` parts indicated that you´re working with `select` `option`s, am I right?

Comment: @Stefan: No, its just checkboxes apart from the submit button. `value="true"` is just the value I've given for checked checkboxes to be submitted.

Comment: I didn´t understand why you would use `value="true"` but try this selector; `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked"')`. It selects all `input` elements of the type "checkbox" that is checked.

Comment: @Stefan: I used `value=true` just because the property the entity has is a boolean, so when I get the value at the server end I see if its "true"(the String "true" not the boolean "true") and then I just convert that to boolean true to do the rest of the business logic. It could be anything but I had to convert that into boolean value to work the business logic at the server end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
setInterval(submit_me, 600000); // (1000 * 60 * 10 = 600000)

function submit_me() {

    $('#form').submit();

}
```

Shorter version:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#form').submit(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. do I need to add an `id=form` to make the above code work? just with form element it doesn't the page doesn't go anywhere?

Comment: That's correct. Or you could enter the ID that your form already has.

Comment: I added `id=form` to the form element but the page doesn't go anywhere. I tried to test the `setTimeOut(..)` with an alert box but even that doesn't work. This forum is very rightly named, I feel my stackoverflown :(.

Comment: @Jeffery: I am not sure why but when I removed the `setTimeout(..)` from inside `$(document).ready(function() {..}` then only the `setTimeout(..)` works but `setTimeout($('#form').submit(), 600000);` is not working as the form doesn't submit :(

Comment: I've edited my post. It looked like you can't just call a jQuery command in there. So I made a tiny edit to it and got it working. Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/GTZWH/

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But I wanted to send the auto-submit to map to a different method in the controller than when the user submits the form himself. I think I am going to learn a bit about it now. Many many thanks for the replies :).

Comment: It works all well only until the user hits the refresh button because the timer restarts again after that from 0 :).

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout(function, millisDelay)`

```
$("document").ready(function() {            
    setTimeout(function(){
        var checkedInputElements = $(":input[value=true]");
        var paramNames = [];
        jQuery.each(checkedInputElements, function() {
            var paramName = $(this).attr("name");
            paramNames.push(paramName);
        });
        $("form").submit(function() {
            jQuery.post({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "http://localhost:8080/wickedlynotsmart/auto-submit-form",
              data: paramNames
          });
          return true;
        });
    }, 600000);
});
```

NB. `setTimeout(function, millisDelay)` is a built in javascript function - it's not part of jQuery or any other library

With a success handler:

```
$("document").ready(function() {            
    setTimeout(function(){
        var checkedInputElements = $(":input[value=true]");
        var paramNames = [];
        jQuery.each(checkedInputElements, function() {
            var paramName = $(this).attr("name");
            paramNames.push(paramName);
        });
        $("form").submit(function() {
            jQuery.post({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "http://localhost:8080/wickedlynotsmart/auto-submit-form",
              data: paramNames,
              success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  alert(data); //data contains the response from the servlet you posted to.
                  document.location = "http://Where-I-want-to-redirect-to";
              }
          });
          return true;
        });
    }, 600000);
});
```

Comment: The page doesn't go anywhere with the code above :(. What am I missing?

Comment: I tried     `$("document").ready(function() {            
        setTimeout(20000, function(){
   alert("20 seconds are over");
        });
    });` just for testing but even that doesn't seem to work. What could I be missing? I do have `jquery-1.5.js` imported to the page.

Comment: You've got the variables the wrong way round - I changed it after first answering - reload the page to see my updated answer. e.g. `setTimeout(function(){alert("20 secs");}, 20000);`

Comment: Even that's not working, I've no idea what going on. I am going to send my whole page with an EDIT in the question. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: The alert worked. I was mistakenly having the javascript code inside `$("document").ready(function() { .. }` so may be that was why it wasn't working. But main problem is still there as the page doesn't  go anywhere.

Comment: Try `$(document)` instead of `$("document")` for the first problem.
The second is that you are not telling it to go anywhere - you are doing an asynchronous post, i.e. background post.  You can put a success handler to handle the response, then do a re-direct, or you can actually construct a new form from each parameter that's checked and submit it using $("#myFormId").submit().  But it depends what you want to do?  Does the servlet you are posting to just redirect at the end, or does it return HTML to be rendered?

Comment: The controller I am posting this form to uses the values of all the parameters of the checked checkboxes and does some business logic with and return a page with the result based on the checkboxes that were checked. Its like an one page online test where checkboxes are the options given to the user to check and the test to be submitted automatically if the user doesnt do it after 10 min. I can't afford to add a new form for every checkbox firstly I know very little about jquery and secondly because this module works just fine apart from the fact that the auto submit also needs to be addedtoit.

Comment: The code above is not working :(. Jeffrey's code has worked but I was actually wanting to send the auto-submit to map to a different request than the one when the user submits the form. I think I am going to spend a few hours to learn sending http requests using jquery. Many many thanks for your replies.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't actually answer my question.  The thing that receives the form input, does it generate HTML and output it, or does it redirect you?  If it redirects you, you can do that same re-direct on the client in the success function as I stated in my edited answer above.  If it just generates HTML and outputs that, then you need to take that HTML and render it i.e. `$(document).html(data)`

Comment: If you just want to change the location the form sends to, `$('#myFormId').attr("action", "myNewURL"); 
$('#myFormId').submit();` is the easiest way?

Comment: No, the thing that receives the form data doesn't redirect to any other page. It shows some data dynamically generated based on the checked boxes on the form. At least for now it doesn't redirect to any other page but I will be doing a redirect to avoid resubmitting the form by refreshing the page but the dynamically generated data will still need to be displayed on the redirected page.

Comment: Yep, I think that's probably the easiest way to to send the form to a different URL for auto submit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Are anythin working at all? Use `console.log()` or `alert()` to follow the code.

You´re passing the `document` as a string.

```
$("document").ready(function() { ...
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function() { ...
```

Regarding the timer to submit the form; your example just bind the ajax post to the forms submit event, it doesn´t submit the form or send the ajax request.

Do you want the form to be submited after 10 minutes? Should the user be able to check/uncheck the checkboxes during that time or should the (unchecked) checkboxes be selected and added to `paramNames` on document ready?

**UPDATE**

Created a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/cayHz/);

HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
    1 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
    2 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" />
    3 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit form" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log('document ready'); // DEBUG

    setTimeout(function() {

        console.log('setTimeout()'); // DEBUG
        submitForm();

    }, 1000 * 5); // 5 seconds

    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
        console.log('submit event'); // DEBUG
        submitForm();
    });

});

var submitForm = function() {

    console.log('submitForm()'); // DEBUG

    var $checkedInputElements = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    var paramNames = [];

    $checkedInputElements.each(function() {
        paramNames.push($(this).attr("name"));
    });

    console.log('paramNames =', paramNames); // DEBUG

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: paramNames,
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log('Done: ', textStatus); // DEBUG
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    return true;
};
```

Comment: @Stephan: I knew something must have been wrong with my jquery code. Yeah I want the form to be auto submitted in 10 minutes if the user doesn't do that himself. All the checkboxes checked by that time would remain checked and get stored in the "paramNames" String array. Its like online test with a timer. If the user doesn't submit the test himself after the time is over the test gets submitted automatically.