# How to include form submit in countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, countdown

I am a beginner in javascript. There is a countdown timer in javascript, in which i wan to include a automatic form submit after duration ends. How can I do it? Please help me. The code is given bellow.

```
     <script>
    function countdown(minutes) {
    var seconds = 60;
    var mins = minutes;
    function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("clockdiv");
    var current_minutes = mins-1;
    seconds--;

   var minutesSpan = counter.querySelector('.minutes');
   var secondsSpan = counter.querySelector('.seconds');


minutesSpan.innerHTML = current_minutes.toString();
secondsSpan.innerHTML = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);

    if( seconds > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    } else {

        if(mins > 1){

           // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithorst
           setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);

        }
    }


}


tick();

}

countdown(<?php echo $duration?>); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mins==0 && seconds==0){
form=document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.submit();
}
```

Add this into the countdown function.
If both minutes and seconds are 0 submit the first form found in your html.

Answer (score 0):

As already shown on Stack Overflow: 
[How to set a timer using jQuery to sent HTTP post data of HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891735/how-to-set-a-timer-using-jquery-to-sent-http-post-data-of-html-form)

You could use jQuery (include it in `head` tag):

```
 setTimeout(function() { $('#form').submit(); }, 5000);
```

Where your form has `id="form"` and the delay is of `5s`.